# How to echo a variable?

Tags: linux, shell

I use `echo "smth $string"`, but I want that it would echo smth $string, not variable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape the `$`:

```
echo "smth \$string"
```

Or maybe use single quotes

```
echo 'smth $string'
```

Answer (score 2):

does this work?

```
echo "smth \$string"
```